# TableView is not populating after populated from loaded array

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview

I have read through the similar questions, but am still stuck.

I have an array in a separate swift file called getSkills.  It connects to a Firebase database and returns the skills into a variable/array called mySkills.

```
func getSkills(owner: String) {

    mySkills = []
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("Skills").order(by: "SkillName").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let e = error {
            print(e)
            //TO DO: show error on screen
        } else {
            if let safeDocs = querySnapshot?.documents {
                for doc in safeDocs {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    if let sklName = data["SkillName"] as? String,
                       let sklType = data["SkillType"] as? String,
                       let sklLevel = data["SkillLevel"] as? String,
                       let sklIsTimed = data["isTimed"] as? Bool,
                       let sklSecs : Int = data["Seconds"] as? Int,
                       let sklOwner = data["Owner"] as? String,
                       let sklID = doc.documentID as? String {
                            let newSkill = Skill(id: sklID, name: sklName, type: sklType, isTimed: sklIsTimed, seconds: sklSecs, level: sklLevel, owner: sklOwner)
                                mySkills.append(newSkill)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

In a separate swift view controller, I am calling the getSkills function in ViewDidLoad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    skillList.dataSource = self
    skillList.delegate = self
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        getSkills(owner: getUserID())
        print(mySkills.count)
        self.skillList.reloadData()
    }
```

However, when the View Controller displays in the simulator the tableview is not populated with the list of Skills.

I can get the issue to work with a "LoadData()" function in the View Controller.  However, I'm trying to build a reusable getSkills function that I can call in multiple locations as opposed to writing the same code over and over.

I've tried the following things:

- Dispatch Main Queue in the getSkills function
- Dispatch main queue in the ViewController itself
- Moving the Dispatch main queue lines to the ViewWillAppear function on the ViewController.
- wrapping the mySkills.append in the getSkills function within Dispatch Main Queue

Any ideas?

Comment: getSkills makes an asynchronous call so the print and reloadData calls are done before you have received any data

Comment: @Joakim Okay, thanks.  I kind of figured it was something like that.  How do I solve my problem?

Comment: Do the reload after the for loop for quick fix.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini, yep.  That would work.  Except I'm trying to build a general function that I can use in multiple view controllers to refresh different table views.  Is there a way to add the reload after the loop that is dynamic and knows what table view to reload?  Or to make the reload generic?

Comment: After thinking though the comments above, I added a new variable to the getSkills function: tblView: UITableView.  That allowed me to pass into the getSkills function the table view that needed to be refreshed and reloaded.  I think added the Dispatch Main Queue function to the getSkills and it seems to work.  I would still like to understand if there is a way to NOT add the tblView as an input, since I may need to use the getSkills function without a table view, but at least it gets me moving forward.

Comment: You need a completion handler. That is the only way to know when your data has arrived so you can print the result, reload the table, whatever.

Comment: @matt, any suggestions about you tube videos about how to write completion handlers?  I've run into another async issue, I think.  Argh!  Thanks for any direction you can give.

Comment: I've written extensively on this topic. For example, see http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/ (and the two articles that precede it in the series); and if you want to know about the Combine Framework way (which in some ways I like better), see my https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/. I don't do videos, sorry.